# JavaScript object inside Multiple array merge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have one object inside the object list of array values, I want to merge the object value
Thanks for Help

```
const List = {
    school1: [{studentname:'1'},{studentname:'2'}]
    school2: [{studentname:'21'},{studentname:'22'}] 
    school3: [{studentname:'31'},{studentname:'32'}]
}

Trying Get like this 
const List = [{studentname:'1'},{studentname:'2'},{studentname:'21'},{studentname:'22'},{studentname:'31'},{studentname:'32'}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the list structure given or can you change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and  [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get the desired result:

```js
const List = {
    school1: [{studentname:'1'},{studentname:'2'}],
    school2: [{studentname:'21'},{studentname:'22'}], 
    school3: [{studentname:'31'},{studentname:'32'}]
}

const result = Object.values(List).flat();
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = {
    a1: [{name:'s1'}, {name: 's2'}],
    a2: [{name:'s3'}, {name: 's4'}],
    a3: [{name:'s5'}, {name: 's6'}],
}
var list = [];
Object.keys(a).forEach(x => {list = [...list, ...a[x]]})
console.log(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force solution:

```js
const List = {
    school1: [{studentname:'1'},{studentname:'2'}],
    school2: [{studentname:'21'},{studentname:'22'}],
    school3: [{studentname:'31'},{studentname:'32'}]
}

let List2 = [];
for(let i of Object.values(List)){
    List2.push(i)
}
console.log(List2)
```